# Time of stay on webpage

Tags: time, google-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I want to know the time a user spends to fill a particular field in the page and want to trigger an event if the user spends more than 5 minutes to answer a question on that page.

I've looking at various Web Analytical tools like Crazyegg, Lucky Orange. Google Analytics for my website and i did not find any of them have this feature.

Is there any way that i can get this feature in my website.

I've been researching to get the perfect fit but in vain.

Any advice would help.
Thank you.

Comment: Google Analytics has a [`ga:timeOnPage` metric](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_timeonpage). Does that not meet your needs? if not why not create a custom metric and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the Google Tag Manager you should be able to do this with Google Analytics:

1. Add a Datalayer to your page, which fires if a User starts filling your form/field.
2. Build a Event, Listening on this Datalayer and send a Timestep (for example: Category = Form, Action = Start, Label = {{Timestamp}}) Now you know then a User started interacting with your form.
3. Build a second Datalayer, fireing when the User sends your form. Build a Event for this and send your second Timestamp to GA (for example: Category = Form, Action = End, Label = {{Timestamp}}) - now you know how long a user needs for your form.

**Trigger the Event**

1. Here we can use the same Datalayer, we used with the Event-Tracking.
2. Build a Triger for your Event, listening on the Datalayer and then starts a Countdown (Timer-Trigger in GTM)
3. In the Timer-Trigger rules you have to specify, that the Trigger should not fire if the second Datalayer (Datalayer-End) fired allready.

[image]